# ¿Como funcionan las variables globales en google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Las globales que quiero usar son la hoja actual , una carpeta donde guardare archivos, y la fecha y hora formateada para usarla en el nombre del archivo.

```
   var FechaHoraActual = new Date();
  const  CarpetaDestino : DriveApp.getFolderById("IDCARPETA");
     var fechaString : Utilities.formatDate(FechaHoraActual; "GMT-5", "yyyy/MM/dd- HH:mm");
    const ss : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

Sin embargo cuando uso  globales el activador `onOpen(e)` no se ejecuta.
¿ porque pasa esto? , cuando tenia las variables dentro de las funciones si ejecutaba el activador, que agregaba un menu a la hoja.

En este caso como puedo usar globales en GAS? Sin necesidad de  estar pegando esas variables en cada funcion y que funcionen mis activadores simples?

Answer (score 0):

No se te ayudará pero puede servirte.
Las constantes globales yo las defino fuera de las funciones con var , en uno de los archivos .gs defino todas las constantes.Esto tiene sus pros y sus contras.

Para lo que comentas, quentiendo que es en una ejecucion se modifican unos valores que deben ser tenidos en cuenta en la siguiente, yo utilizo una hoja y para cada valor o grupo de valores, defino un rango con nombre. Solo hay que leer el valor cuando se inicia la ejecución y guardar el nuevo valor antes de finalizar.

Espero que se ayude.
Saludos.

Comment: No mi problemas es que si uso variables globares , fuera de una funcion , mi funcion de activador  `onOpen()`  no se activa,se supone que cuando abro la hoja la funcion  `onOpen()`  se ejectura.

Answer (score 0):

En tu pregunta estas usando ".getActiveSpreadsheet()" y es la hoja activa.
Si quieres definir una variable global constante puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
const libro = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxx');

function onOpen(e) {
  libro.getSheetByName('Hoja 1').getRange('A1').setValue('TEST');
}
```

Creo esa era tu consulta, si no te pido reformularla

Answer (score 0):

He tenido el mismo problema, aparentemente hay conflictos con las variables globales y la función onOpen(), yo lo he resuelto creando una función para hacer la llamada, y luego instanciandola desde otras funciones.

```
function getData(sheetCalled, rangeCalled) {
  var get_spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(get_spreadSheet);
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheetCalled);
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange(rangeCalled + lastRow);
  var data = myRange.getValues();
  return (data);
}
function myfunction(){
  Logger.log(getData("Hoja 1", "A2:A"));
}
```

También puedes hacerlo con una clase:

```
class SpreadSheet {
  constructor() {
    this.spreadSheet = this.getSpreadSheet();
  }

  getSpreadSheet() {
    try {
      var get_spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
      return SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(get_spreadSheet);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al obtener la hoja:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  async getSheet(sheetName, rangeCall) {
    try {
      var sheet = this.spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      var myRange = sheet.getRange(rangeCall + lastRow);
      var values = myRange.getValues();
      return values;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al obtener la hoja:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

function llamarclase(){
  const mySpreadSheet = new SpreadSheet();
  mySpreadSheet.getSheet("Hoja 1", "C2:C").then((datosRango) => {
    console.log('Datos del rango:', datosRango);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El activador `onOpen(e)` se ejecuta cuando se abre un documento, pero hay que tener en cuenta algunas consideraciones con respecto al uso de variables globales. La declaración y asignación de variables globales fuera de una función puede ser problemática en ciertos casos.

GAS utiliza js y no ts, tenlo en cuenta.

Te dejo un ejemplo de código que podría ayudarte:

```
var FechaHoraActual;

function onOpen(e) {
  // Inicialización de variables globales en onOpen
  FechaHoraActual = new Date();
  CarpetaDestino = DriveApp.getFolderById("IDCARPETA");

  // Agregar un menú al abrir la hoja
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Mi Menú');
  menu.addItem('Mi Función', 'miFuncion');
  menu.addToUi();
}

function miFuncion() {
  // Acceder a variables globales
  var fechaString = Utilities.formatDate(FechaHoraActual, "GMT-5", "yyyy/MM/dd- HH:mm");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Resto del código de la función
}
```